# How to keep dumplings from quickly drying out

Tags: dumplings

Last night, I assembled a few (around 2 dozen) dumplings from simple wrappers made from just flour and boiling water. I kept the wrappers under a wet towel because the edges started to dry out really quickly, but by the time I was done assembling them all, the filled dumplings were getting dry.

Is there a way, other than keeping everything under a damp towel, to keep them from drying out so quickly?

I should also add that I left the dough to rise in the fridge for a day in a kinda damp towel in a plastic container, maybe that has to do with it? But the dough wasn't dry went a rolled it out.

Comment: How many did you roll out in one go?

Comment: My in-laws (who are Chinese) add a little oil to their "wrapper dough" as well. And I also ask, how many did you roll out in one go?

Comment: @Stephie Not that many! See edit.

Answer (score 2):

Dumpling wrappers are by nature prone to drying out. A wet towel will only work to a degree. If the filled dumplings dry out slightly, it’s not too critical (note that I wrote *slightly*), so temporarily covering them with a humid towel or putting them in a sealed container should suffice, but the wrappers alone will become brittle and unusable.

If you don’t have a bunch of friends or family so that you can work in an assembly-line, rolling just a few wrappers at time is the best way. How many will depend on your how nimble your fingers are and what kind of pleat you are doing. Maybe start with around five to ten and adjust accordingly.

Then either cook all dumplings after you are done wrapping, or cook batches while rolling, filling and pleating the next. This will need some more time management and multitasking and it’s your choice which one fits your needs and general preferences.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're suggesting I roll out some wrappers, fill them, cook them, eat/freeze them and then finally repeat with a few more.

Comment: Nah, roll out a few, fill them and set them aside under a humid towel. Repeat until done. Then cook and enjoy. Or cook in parallel, for larger batches. But that’ll mean more multitasking, of course.

Comment: *Other than keeping everything under a damp towel*, since that's what I did last time I was looking for a trick or different dough recipe, like adding oil, or something.